# Rest api backend is reachable n serving "start" message when accessed by IP n domain,but get "Cannot GET"error when accessing routes using domain name

Tags: node.js, express, rest, routes, mern

My rest api backend is reachable and serving the "start" message when accessed through both the IP address and the domain name, but it encountering a "Cannot GET" error when accessing specific routes using the domain name.

When i request the ip address the msg comes "start", this is default msg which i have done in code app.js file. This ip address works fine in my all routes like : 314.212.32:5050/api/v1/auth/user/login

//note : here i have placed a demo ip address.

This will return a msg something like wellcome and if the email or pass is wrong it will return no user exist.
this is working as expected. but when i do the same thing with my domain, here i am just replacing the ip address with domain, that's it no other changes, The start msg is coming from backend, when the domain is requested "api.domain.com" this means the dns and the other configs are fine. but when i request on api.domain.com/api/v1/auth/user/login, it shows "Cannot GET /api/v1/auth/user/login".

i don't know where i am missing.

Here is my app.js file code

```
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

const connectDB = require("./db/connect");

```
const authenticate = require("./middlewares/authentication");
const userAuthRouter = require("./routes/userAuthRouter");
const productUserRouter = require("./routes/productUserRouter");
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRouter");
const productVendorRouter = require("./routes/productVendorRouter");
const vendorRouter = require("./routes/vendorRouter");
const frontendRouter = require("./routes/frontendRouter");
const adminAuthRouter = require("./routes/adminAuthRouter");
const eventRouter = require("./routes/eventRouter");
const clubRouter = require("./routes/clubRouter");
const propsRouter = require('./routes/propsRouters');
const vendorRegisterRouter = require("./routes/vendorRegisterRouter");
const vendorLoginRouter = require("./routes/vendorLoginRouter");
const giftRouter = require("./routes/giftRouter");
const cardRouter = require("./routes/cardRouter");
const bagRouter = require("./routes/bagRouter");
const communityRouter = require("./routes/communityRouter");
const contentRouter = require("./routes/contentRouter");
const tileRouter = require("./routes/tileRouter");
const paymentRouter = require("./routes/paymentRouter");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("start...");
});

app.use("/api/v1/auth/user", userAuthRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/auth/vendorL", vendorLoginRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/auth/vendorR", authenticate, vendorRegisterRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/productUser", authenticate, productUserRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/user", authenticate, userRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/productVendor", authenticate, productVendorRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/vendor", authenticate, vendorRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/frontend", authenticate, frontendRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/admin", adminAuthRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/event", authenticate, eventRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/club", authenticate, clubRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/props", authenticate, propsRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/gifts", authenticate, giftRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/card", authenticate, cardRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/bag", authenticate, bagRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/community", authenticate, communityRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/content", authenticate, contentRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/tile", authenticate, tileRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/payment", paymentRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5050;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening to the port ${port}.`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

Any help would means a lot.